# map перезаписывает элемент а не добавляет

Tags: c++

Метод map перезаписывает элемент а не добавляет новый, пробовал и методом emplace и pair, в чем ошибка подскажите?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


class test1
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int age;
public:
    test1() {};
    test1(std::string name, int age)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
    }
    bool operator < (const test1 & a) const
    {
        return (this->name < a.name) && (this->age < a.age);
    }

    std::string GetName() const
    {
        return this->name;
    }
    int GetAge() const
    {
        return this->age;
    }

    friend ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const test1 & a)
    {
        os << "name: " << a.GetName() << " " << "age : " << a.GetAge();
        return os;
    }
};

class test2
{
private:
    std::string bag;
    std::string color;
public:
    test2() {};
    test2(std::string bagName, std::string color)
    {
        this->bag = bagName;
        this->color = color;
    }
    std::string GetBag() const
    {
        return this->bag;
    }
    std::string Color() const
    {
        return this->color;
    }
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const test2 & a)
    {
        os << "name: " << a.GetBag() << " " << "age : " << a.Color();
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{

    std::map<test1, test2> myMap;
    test1 user1{ "John", 20 };
    test2 inventory{ "Daykine", "red" };
    myMap.insert(pair<test1, test2>(user1, inventory));

    test1 user2{ "Victor", 20 };
    test2 inventory2{ "Daykine", "blue" };
    myMap.emplace(user2, inventory2);

    test1 user3{ "Victor", 20 };
    test2 inventory3{ "Daykine", "blue" };
    myMap.emplace(user3, inventory3);

    for (auto & item : myMap)
    {
        cout << item.first;
        cout << item.second;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит "не добавляет"??? Map хранит *уникальные* (по ключу) элементы. Он по определению не может ничего "добавить", если такой ключ уже  есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool operator < (const test1 & a) const
{
    if (this->name < a.name){
        return true;
    }else if (this->name == a.name){
        if (this->age < a.age){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

И оператор сравнения у вас неправильно написан как по мне.
С таким оператором уже второй элемент появится, а третий нет (потому-что не std::multimap)

Comment: спасибо большое я понял

Comment: с multimap работает, только вот предподователь задал делать с map. И у меня же вроде бы ключем являються обьекты user1, user2, user3  и они разные, не верно мыслю?

Comment: Разобрался, все работает великолепно, действительно, основная проблема была в  operator <

Comment: Советую упрощать себе жизнь: `return std::tie(name, age) < std::tie(a.name, a.age);`

Answer (score 1):

### Возможно, вам нужен другой контейнер.

Контейнер [std::map](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) хранит уникальные ключи. Если вы добавляете новый элемент с тем же ключом, вы перезапишете старый, который уже имеется в контейнере.

Если вам нужно хранить много элементов с повторяющимися ключами, используйте [std::multimap](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) .